# Should children be selected automatically when using TVS_CHECKBOXES (CTreeCtrl)

Tags: mfc, controls

Yeah, still using MFC...

I have a CTreeCtrl with TVS_CHECKBOXES. When I click on a parent's checkbox, should the children's checkboxes automatically be checked/unchecked? Similarly, if I manually check all children's checkboxes, should the parent's checkbox automatically be checked?

I know that is the expected behavior of a tree control with checkboxes. My question is whether the tree control can do this automatically (which isn't happening in my app) or if I need to code this behavior. I didn't want to code this if it is built-in functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: To my knowledge that logic isn't provided by the standard [tree view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-control-reference) control. You'd have to implement that yourself (unless MFC offers this convenience). [How to Work With State Image Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/work-with-state-image-indexes) should get you started.

Comment: I second @IInspectable's opinion; if you want to have the descendents the same state as the ancestor, you have to do ti manually. There is no lack of people in the Internet saying they had to do it https://www.google.com/search?q=ctreectrl+SetCheck+recursive